# Google_DriveFile Class Not Found Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-drive-api

I'm using the google-api-php-client Library in my project. I'm using Composer to auto load the library in my project. The other classes (ie: Google_Client) are working fine. When I go to instantiate an object, [per the Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Google_DriveFile' not found
```

This is the line causing the error:

```
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the Library was updated, the class name was changed to `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile`, per this [article](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration). The documentation was **not** updated.

Comment: As of 2015, Jule i still see loads of `Google_DriveFile` references in _Drive.php_, thanx for this answer

Comment: Can you please let me know how to include the Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile class ? also where to obtain the file from ?